# React multiple callbacks not updating the local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component called First which is implemented below:

```
function First(props) {

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    props.positiveCallback({key: 'positive', value: 'pos'})
    props.negativeCallback({key: 'negative', value: '-100'})
  }

  return (
   <div><button onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}>FIRST</button></div>
  )
}
```

And I have App.js component.

```
function App() {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState({positive: '+', negative: '-'})

  const handleCounterCallback = (obj) => {

      console.log(obj)

      let newCounter = {...counter}
      newCounter[obj.key] = obj.value

      setCounter(newCounter)
  }

  const handleDisplayClick = () => {
    console.log(counter)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <First positiveCallback = {handleCounterCallback} negativeCallback = {handleCounterCallback} />
      <Second negativeCallback = {handleCounterCallback} />
      <button onClick={() => handleDisplayClick()}>Display</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When handleButtonClick is clicked in First component it triggers multiple callbacks but only the last callback updates the state.

In the example:

```
 props.positiveCallback({key: 'positive', value: 'pos'}) // not updated
 props.negativeCallback({key: 'negative', value: '-100'}) // updated
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As @dupocas suggested, setting state separately for positive and negative will make it far more better.

Answer (score 2):

Both are updating the `state`, your problem is the last one is overwriting the first when you `spread` the previous state (which isn't updated by the time your accessing it, so you are spreading the initial state). An easy workaround is to split `counter` into smaller pieces and update them individually

```
const [positive, setPositive] = useState('+')
const [negative, setNegative] = useState('-')

//This prevents your current code of breaking when accessing counter[key]
const counter = { positive, negative }

const handleCounterCallback = ({ key, value }) => {
   key === 'positive' ? setPositive(value) : setNegative(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if I had the counter object which contained 10-15 properties representing the state then making them smaller would be a pain.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a complex state. You just have to be careful with `spreads`, since states' updates aren't synchronous the value you're spreading may be differente from the expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but `useState` setter is async like `this.setState`. If you want to base on the previous value you should use setter as function and you can store it in one state - change `handleCounterCallback` to

```
const handleCounterCallback = ({key,value}) => {
  setCounter(prev=>({...prev, [key]: value}))
}
```

and that is all. **Always if you want to base on the previous state use setter for the state as function**.

I recommend you to use another hook rather than `useState` which is `useReducer` - I think it will be better for you